# Criar campos input conforme o tamanho de um array

Tags: javascript, json, formulário, jsp

Boa noite, estou recebendo via JSON uma `List` com a estrutura abaixo:

```
anexo: [{cod: 5, nome: "anexo1.pdf"}, {cod: 6, nome: "texto.txt"}]
```

E uso a função abaixo:

```
$.getJSON(url + cod,
                    function (ajax) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < ajax.anexo.length; i++) {
                            //alert(ajax.anexo[i].nome);
                            $.each(ajax.anexo[i], function (k, value) {
                                $("#formAnexo").find($('[name="anexo.' + k + '"]')).each(function () {
                                    setElementValue(this, value, 'anexo.' + k);
                                });
                            });

                        }
                    });
```

Essa função obtém os dados do JSON e preenche o `<textarea>` de meu formulário.
No caso de apenas 1 item, está funcionando. Agora se são 2 ou mais itens, como a estrutura que apresentei no inicio, apenas um dado esta aparecendo no formulário (o último sobrescreve os anteriores - pelo que entendi).

Meu formulário está assim:

```
<label>Anexo:</label>
<textarea rows="5" id="nome" readonly="nome" name="anexo.nome" ></textarea>
```

Como posso corrigir isso, de modo que meu JSON tenha uma `List` de 2 ou mais itens, e que estes sejam acrescentados nesse `textarea`?

Comment: Seu formulário tem um único `textarea` ou vários (em outras palavras, é pro nome de cada item ir parar em um textarea diferente, ou pra todos eles irem pro mesmo textarea, separados por espaços ou quebras de linha por exemplo)? Existe algum elemento com o nome `anexo.cod`? E o que `setElementValue` faz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Há alguns problemas com seu código:

1. Primeiro você itera sobre os elementos do JSON, depois você itera sobre as *propriedades* de cada elemento; no meu entender, bastaria iterar sobre os elementos, não?

   ```
   for (var i = 0; i < ajax.anexo.length; i++) { // Itera sobre os elementos

       //alert(ajax.anexo[i].nome); // Isso me parece correto

       $.each(ajax.anexo[i], function (k, value) { // Itera sobre o elemento?
           // k == "cod", value == 5
           // k == "nome", value == "anexo1.pdf"
   ```
2. O seletor `'[name="anexo.' + k + '"]'` vai selecionar **todos** os elementos com o nome `anexo.nome` (e `anexo.cod`), não interessa em que iteração do loop externo você está. Então sim, os elementos subsequentes vão sobrescrever os anteriores.
3. O método [`find`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) aceita um seletor, um elemento ou um objeto jQuery. Isso está correto:

   ```
   $("#formAnexo").find($('[name="anexo.' + k + '"]')).each
   ```

   mas é mais simples fazer:

   ```
   $("#formAnexo").find('[name="anexo.' + k + '"]').each
   ```

A maneira correta de fazer, depende da sua intenção. Não ficou claro na pergunta se há um único `textarea` ou vários, mas pelo que foi exposto vou assumir que é só um. Nesse caso, sugiro acumular os nomes em uma lista, e no final atribuí-los de uma vez só:

```js
var ajax = { anexo: [{cod: 5, nome: "anexo1.pdf"}, {cod: 6, nome: "texto.txt"}] };

var nomes = [];
for (var i = 0; i < ajax.anexo.length; i++) {
  nomes.push(ajax.anexo[i].nome);
}

$("#formAnexo").find('[name="anexo.nome"]').each(function() {
  this.value = nomes.join("\n");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="formAnexo">
  <label>Anexo:</label>
  <textarea rows="5" id="nome" readonly="nome" name="anexo.nome" ></textarea>
</form>
```

Comment: mgibson, eu acho melhor então colocar tudo dentro do textarea. Como devo fazer então seguindo essa sua lógica?

Comment: @MarciaPereiraReis O exemplo que eu dei coloca os nomes de todos os itens no `textarea`, um por linha. Você quer colocar os códigos também, ou alguma coisa diferente? (por exemplo, alguma formatação...) A propósito, você não *precisa* usar um `textarea` só, é possível (simples até) criar um formulário dinâmico onde o número de componentes é variável, conforme o número de itens. Mas para isso é preciso determinar antes *o que você vai fazer com esses dados*, i.e. quando você for enviá-los de volta ao servidor (se é que vai) como eles serão tratados lá.

Comment: ficou exatamente como eu precisava. Muito obrigada!